# Pokemon Yellow wrap transitions

Tags: java, algorithm, graphics2d

So I've been trying to make a pretty accurate clone of the good old Pokemon Yellow for quite some time now and one puzzling but nonetheless subtle mechanic has puzzled me. As you can see in the uploaded image there is a certain colour manipulation done in two stages after entering a wrap to another game location (such as stairs or entering a building).

One easy (and sloppy) way of achieving this and the one I have been using so far is to make three pngs for each image (sprite tilemaps, town images) all of them with their colours adjusted accordingly to match each stage of the transition. Of course after a while this becomes tremendously time consuming.

So my question is does anyone know any better way of achieving this colour manipulation effect using java and Graphics2D?

Thanks in advance,

Alex

[image: Wrap transition]

Comment: Actually, it is unclear what do you mean, because you didn't provide formal description of what do you really want to archive with your pictures. This question isn't about java or graphics2d, because, of course, there aren't any functions in theese libraries, which will do such image color transition. You should do it by your self, searching for common algorithms or inveting your own.

Comment: @AlexKoukoulas you want to write a code to these transformations of already loaded images right ?

Comment: you might try this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_color. It just maps one color to another . So once you load the image you do this transformation for sprite by mapping the colors in it to other colors using a mapping function that you have loaded from config file for each level.

Comment: Could you add some minimal example for testing? Also, not sure if this is possible, but maybe you can overlay the image with a semi-transparent black rectangle? The effect would be different, but similar enough.

Comment: @VikramBhat Interesting link Vikram thanks I'll give it a look. Indeed I want to approximate this interesting transition effect on every single image rendered on the screen at that time basically

Comment: Could you elaborate on that transition? It seems each picture has only four colors, and in each step they are shifted from yellow -> purple -> cyan -> black until everything is black. Is this correct?

Comment: @tobias_k Hi tobias I've actually tried a similar approach to your suggestion using ` g.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER,alpha))` and then drawing an overlaying rectangle where alpha gets progressively larger but it's still needs a lot of tweaking to actually look like the pictures uploaded.

Comment: @tobias_k Yes this is correct everything is black after the last picture

Comment: You can also find help at http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know whether there's a built-in function for cycling the colors in an image. I think there *should* be, but I could not find one.

Anyhow, one way to do this would be to loop over all the pixels in the image, looking up the color in a predefined list of colors, from bright to dark, and making each pixel "one darker".

```
public static void shiftToBlack(BufferedImage img) {
    // the four colors used in test.png, from bright to dark
    List<Integer> colors = Arrays.asList(-196868, -4088073, -10112268, -12500653);
    for (int i = 0; i < img.getRaster().getWidth(); i++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < img.getRaster().getHeight(); k++) {
            int c = img.getRGB(i, k);
            int index = colors.indexOf(c);
            int c2 = index < colors.size() - 1 ? colors.get(index+1) : c;
            img.setRGB(i, k, c2);
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, this does not scale too well when the image is larger, but for the typical four-color Game Boy screen this should work. Thus, if you are applying any filters such as enlarging the image to be playable on modern screens, or anti-aliasing, you should apply those *after* this color-shift operation. Also, you'll have to adapt the `colors` to the four colors used in your images.

Full example code:

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("test.png"));
JComponent component = new JComponent() {
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics graphics) {
        graphics.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
    };
};
component.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        shiftToBlack(img);
        component.repaint();
    }
});
JFrame frame = new JFrame("test");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.getContentPane().add(component);
frame.pack();
frame.setSize(150, 150);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

And my `test.png`

[image]

Comment: May I ask, how to get to the colors? I don't really understand how I could calculate the correct value.

Comment: @Loki I just put them into a `Set` when I first called that method, then sorted out which one is which.

Comment: ah... I just thought too complicated. I see now how it works. Pretty nice solution.